# Why can I only write one character in my field and then lose focus? [React]

Tags: reactjs

I use a handleinputchange function to update the contents of my field as one writes in it and when I write in it, I can only write one character and I lose focus on the input.

I'm trying to make it possible to modify text fields in a form that already has default values and I can't.

```
const LoginIdsInput = () => {
    return (
      <div className="settings-card">
        <label>Identifiant</label>
        <br />
        <br />
        
    <div className="input-group">
      <IconUser />
      <input
        className="socraft-input-ingroup"
        placeholder="Nom"
        type="text"
        name="firstname"
        value={userData ? userData.firstname : ""}
        onChange={handleInputChange}
      />
       </div>
      </div>
    );
  };


const [userData, setUserData] = useState(null);
const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setUserData({
      ...userData,
      [name]: value,
    });
  };
```

Comment: Is the code you showed (`LoginIdsInput`, `userData`, `handleInputChange`) all inside some other component?

Comment: Everything is in a parent component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining `LoginIdsInput` in the middle of rendering another component. This does not work. Each time you render the parent component, you make a brand new `LoginIdsInput` function. It may have the same text as the last one, but as far as react can tell it's a brand new component. Since the component type has changed, react must unmount the old one and mount the new one, which wipes out focus.

The fix is to move the component out to the top level, so it's just created once. You will need to change userData and handleInputChange to be props.

```
const LoginIdsInput = ({ userData, onChange }) => {
  return (
    <div className="settings-card">
      <label>Identifiant</label>
      <br />
      <br />

      <div className="input-group">
        <IconUser />
        <input
          className="socraft-input-ingroup"
          placeholder="Nom"
          type="text"
          name="firstname"
          value={userData ? userData.firstname : ""}
          onChange={onChange}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const Example = () => {
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState(null);
  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setUserData({
      ...userData,
      [name]: value,
    });
  };

  return <LoginIdsInput userData={userData} onChange={handleInputChange} />;
};
```